# Moving a django postgres database to a new server leads to InconsistentMigrationHistory

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have an database dump file of my PostgreSQL database that was created by `pg_dump`.

I transfer this file to a new server. I also transferred all the relevant `models.py` files to this never server. I used the following command to load in all the data on the new server.

```
gunzip -c dump_file | psql -p port db_name db_user
```

I configured Django to access this database and I can query the data using `manage.py shell_plus`. For eaxmple, I can run `Images.objects.all().count()`which returns the correct number, i.e. the same number of image objects as were present on the old server.

Considering this is a different server, it does not contain any of the original migration files. 
I used `./manage.py makemigrations` to create the migrations files. This appears to work properly and migration files are created for each of my `installed_apps`.

Next, I run `./manage.py migrate`. This leads to the following error:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration shapes.0001_initial is applied before its dependency bsdfs.0002_auto_20200527_1647 on database 'default'.
```

All the answer on SO say to simply uncomment `shapes` from the `installed_apps` list, but this does not work because this leads to the following error when I'm importing it in the `models.py.` The models are extrmely big, and uncommenting each instance where `shapes` is being used it not possible.

`RuntimeError: Model class shapes.models.Material doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS`

What can I do to migrate the database properly?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you didn't have any migrations for the old db.
I assume pg_dump contained all the table-linkage information.

In this case, after running `makemigrations` you could try and create a table called `django_migrations` and manually insert a row that tells django that the 'initial migration' already ran (since your db is in sync with your code). 
And when you run `migrate`, it should say, there's nothing to migrate.
And if later you change your model, the new migrations should be compatible, because your db is in sync now with your code.

If your app is 'contenttypes' and the filename of the migration is '0001_initial.py', you just set some past date for the applied column.

[image: pgadmin 4 view of django_migrations table]

Comment: Hi, I indeed don't have any old migrations. This approach sounds promising. Could you elaborate: How/where to create this new table? Through `psql`? And what should the row be exactly?

Comment: Hi, sure, updated my answer with a screenshot. You create the table in your postgres db. (where usually you have auth_user table, django_session etc.)